# Rails nested resources, how do I create two new resources when I need the other's id in the GET request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, nested

Pretty much as the title suggest. I have two models, routes like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :books
end
```

- which gives me exactly the kind of urls I'm looking for. The problem is that I need to have a logic where a *not* logged in user can go in and click "create book", and in the new-page chose to click "new user" or "I have an account", which via javascript loads a form for a new user with all its params, or loads a form with only email and password. How do I create this route to work? With these routes it seems I get the path `/users/:user_id/books/new`, but then I need the user's ID, which I don't have.

Any Ideas?

By the way. User has_many :books, Book belongs_to :user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the route without the user id:

```
# with user_id
resources :users do
  resources :books
end
# without user_id
resources :books
```

It looks dangerous btw to have a user id in the URL. That means that anyone can access the the books of any user, just by changing the URL. The ID of the current user should not appear in your routes at all, but should always use cookies or sessions.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. I will rewrite it to use sessions. Not that I will argue against using sessions here, but I guess you _could_ restrict a user from seeing only his own books thou, no? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but exposing the user's ID is clumsy at best and dangerous at worst.